# Compactar array removendo zeros [C]

Tags: c, array

Questão:

> Faça um programa que leia um vetor de 15 posições e o compacte, ou seja, elimine
>   as posições com valor zero. Para isso, todos os elementos à frente do valor zero,
>   devem ser movidos uma posição para trás no vetor.

Meu problema é o seguinte:
Quando se colocado na execução 3 Dígitos 0 seguidos os números após os {0} são simplesmente apagados

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {    

    int vet[10];
    int i,aux, s=1, c=0, l;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){ //entrada de dados
        printf("Digite o valor da posicao %d do vetor: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&vet[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(vet[i] == 0){
            c++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){ 
        if(vet[i] == 0){
            if(vet[i+1] == 0) s=2;
            aux=vet[i];
            vet[i]=vet[i+s];
            vet[i+1]=aux;
            s++;
        }
    }
    l = i - c;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<l; i++){
        if(vet[i] != 0){
            printf("VetorFinal [%d] = %d\n",i+1,vet[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é manter um índice para a **posição de cópia** e outro para a **posição de leitura**. A posição de cópia anda para frente quando recebe um número diferente de `0`, já a de leitura sempre anda para frente. Ao término deste processo, a posição de cópia será o tamanho do vetor compactado.

Nesse loop, há uma **invariante**. No caso a invariante é que sempre ao final do loop a variável `pos_copia` está apontando para uma posição a frente do último elemento do novo vetor compactado.

A **garantia de término** do loop também pode ser conferida, uma vez que a variável `pos_leitura` sempre anda para frente e nunca lê mais elementos do que existiam no vetor original.

Uma possível implementação do programa é apresentada a seguir.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_TAM 5

int main()
{ 
    int vet[MAX_TAM];

    // lê entrada
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_TAM; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite o valor da posicao %d do vetor: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }

    // realiza-se a cópia utilizando dois índices
    int pos_copia = 0;
    for(int pos_leitura = 0; pos_leitura < MAX_TAM; pos_leitura++)
    {
        if(vet[pos_leitura] == 0)
            continue;

        vet[pos_copia] = vet[pos_leitura];
        pos_copia++;
    }

    // imprime o resultado
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < pos_copia; i++)
        printf("VetorFinal [%d] = %d\n", i + 1, vet[i]);
}
```

Comment: boa solução, fácil de entender

Answer (score 2):

Já tem algumas respostas com soluções alternativas à questão que pretende resolver, mas é sempre bom percebermos onde erramos e o que não serve para o nosso objetivo. É neste ponto que a minha resposta se foca.

Começando pelo segundo `for`:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    if(vet[i] == 0){
        c++;
    }
}
```

Este `for` contabiliza as casas com 0 para poder descontar essa quantidade do tamanho e mostrar o tamanho final correto, mas é desnecessário fazer isto num bloco aparte, uma vez que pode faze-lo no `for` que remove os zeros. Ainda assim este não quebra a lógica.

O problema vem no `for` que se segue:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){ 
    if(vet[i] == 0){
        if(vet[i+1] == 0) s=2;
        aux=vet[i];
        vet[i]=vet[i+s];
        vet[i+1]=aux;
        s++;
    }
}
```

Ele tem vários problemas na verdade. A segunda condição, o `if(vet[i+1] == 0) s=2;`, apenas permite ver se tem dois zeros seguidos para trocar com o elemento 2 casas à frente. Mas e se tiver 3 ? ou 4 ? Nunca dará para fazer apenas assim com um `if` pois você não sabe a quantidade de zeros seguidos. Isso teria de ser trocado por um loop para achar o próximo elemento diferente de 0, ou o fim se não houver mais nenhum pela frente. Nesse loop o `s` teria que começar sempre em 1, para partir da casa à frente onde está o zero.

Depois a troca entre os dois elementos também não ficou correta, o `vet[i+1]=aux;`, pois usa `i+1` quando devia usar `i+s`.

Para corrigir apenas o seu segundo `for` pode fazer assim:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    if(vet[i] == 0){
        s = 1; //começa sempre em 1
        while(i + s < 10 && vet[i+s] == 0){ //com while em vez de if
            s++;
        }
        if (i + s >= 10){ //se não tem mais zeros à frente para trocar termina
            break;
        }
        aux=vet[i];
        vet[i]=vet[i+s];
        vet[i+s]=aux; //agora i+s
        //sem o incremento s++;
    }
}
l = 10 - c;
```

Note que tive que incluir o `l = 10 - c;` pois o `i` já não acaba necessariamente no fim, o que faz com que o antigo `l = i - c;` nem sempre funcione corretamente.

[Veja esta alteração a funcionar no ideone](https://ideone.com/pIQWSt)

É importante salientar que existem melhores algoritmos para este problema, que não só são mais simples como mais eficientes. Um deles é o que está na [resposta colocada pelo alandplm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/389107/82711). Apenas mostrei como corrigir a logica que escreveu para fazer o pretendido.

Comment: +1 por ter mostrado o motivo pela qual o código não funciona, respondendo efetivamente a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa fazer a troca de conteúdo, apenas precisa mover as posições seguintes para a anterior quando for zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int vet[15];
    int i, j, lim=15, k;

    for (i=0;i<15;i++) { //entrada de dados
         printf("Digite o valor da posicao %d do vetor: ",i+1);
         scanf("%d",&vet[i]);
    }
    do {
        k = 0;
        for (i=0;i<lim;i++) {
             if (vet[i]==0) {
                 for (j=i+1; j<lim; j++)
                        vet[j-1] = vet[j];
                 lim--;
                 k++;
             }
        }
    } while (k > 0);
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<lim;i++) {
         printf("VetorFinal [%d] = %d\n",i,vet[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Essa solução apresenta problemas. Entrando apenas 5 elementos para simplificar, por exemplo os seguintes erros ocorrem: entrada (0,0,0,1,2) -> saída (0,1,2); entrada (0,0,0,0,0) -> saída (0,0), entrada (1,2,0,0,3) -> saída (1,2,0,3).

Comment: Código corrigido.